# How to Multicall a non contract function in web3 python?

Tags: web3js, web3.py, json-rpc, bsc, rpc

The method to aggregate functions belonging to contracts is given in this library: https://pypi.org/project/web3-multicall/

But my question is, how can I aggregate a basic web3 function (that is not a part of any contract) too using Multicall?

In my case, I want to get multiple transaction receipts/timestamps (using the `web3.eth.get_transaction_receipt()` or `web3.eth.getBlock().timestamp` function) via a single API call.

Would it be possible for them or any other basic non-contract functions such as `web.eth.eth_balance()` to be used with the Multicall feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will give you an example.
Imagine you want to get balances of 100 addresses.

There are two general options:

1. Your Backend/Frontend calls blockchain a 100 times.
2. You write a SmartContract function that receives an array of 100 addresses and in turn returns an array of 100 corresponding balances.

The second option is the way to go.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Do you know any public SmartContract which returns the timestamp of a block (similar to `web3.eth.getBlock().timestamp`), that I can directly use?

Comment: @DEEPAKS.V. - Yes, the Multicall contract (linked in another comment) does have a `getCurrentBlockTimestamp` to fetch that. Just note that you wouldn't be able to provide an arbitrary block number; it only shows the most recent block's timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

You will get answer at https://github.com/mds1/multicall, a smart contract on many chains.

Comment: You aren't answering the question: how to use multicall to call a non contract function in web3 python?